# How to run source code of an Android app downloaded from Github without the use of an IDE?

Tags: android

So I would like to do it without importing the project into Android Studio. Is it possible?

Comment: If you find a `.apk` file then you can put that into your phone and it'll probably run. Otherwise, you need to somehow compile the code using the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the project build with Gradle

1. install [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)
2. install [Gradle](https://gradle.org/install)
3. open Terminal switch to the project directory,use command "gradle build "

Answer (score 0):

If there's an APK included you can just install the APK using ADB.